# Need Formula Excel how to delete a specific character in long URL

Tags: excel, formula

somebody help me...
In Excel, how the formula to remove all chars after "?ref" In other words only need like this http://www.domain.com/avo/smith-hendry-487895 and so on.
Bellow the sample data:

```
http://www.domain.com/avo/smith-hendry-482225?ref=cr-sr%7Cnormal%7C23%7C15
http://www.domain.com/avo/merry-77789?ref=cr-sr%7Cnormal%7C15%7C24
http://www.domain.com/avo/margaret-anna-675000?ref=cr-sr%7Cnormal%7C19%7C11
```

***please in Formula, not macro or vbs, thank you so much***

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried yet. Show us your code an findings

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do something like this:

```
=substring(<source-cell>, 1 , search(<source-cell>,"?ref"))
```

Not 100% sure about syntax, but the idea should be clear.

EDIT:

Here is a working solution:

```
=MID(F3,1,FIND("?ref",F3)-1)
```

It assumes that the source URL is in cell **F3**.

Comment: not work... please help i really not good to understand formula in Excel.  Just say the data location in (F1:F999)

Comment: ok FDavidov, works.. thanks bro.. it is posibble to make the result (say that formula in F1) become have a link (same URL) and clickable in cell?

Comment: 1) If my solution works, you may consider marking it as such and up-voting. 2) I don't think that is possible. See? When you type into a cell something that looks like a URL, Excel automatically recognizes it as a link and converts it to that. In your case, you are creating a string that results to look like a URL. In any case, I don't know how I would do that.

Comment: already vote..   who can help me here and give solution automaticly i give vote, no problem...   yaa thanks FDavidov

Comment: @JhonDoe. I found one thing that could do the HYPERLINK thing. You can write in cell (say) M3: `=HYPERLINK(J3)` where J3 is the cell where you wrote the formula I suggested. This will make cell M3 clickable as a link. By the way, your up-vote appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
=LEFT(B3, FIND("?ref",B3,1)-1)
```

Here my B3 cell value is

> http://www.domain.com/avo/smith-hendry-482225?ref=cr-sr%7Cnormal%7C23%7C15

and the above formula will give

> http://www.domain.com/avo/smith-hendry-482225

Edited Formula to convert the result to string

```
=HYPERLINK(LEFT(B3, FIND("?",B3,1)-1),LEFT(B3, FIND("?",B3,1)-1))
```

Comment: ok Siva, works.. thanks bro.. it is posibble to make the result (saya that formula in F1) become have a link (same URL) and clickable in cell?

Comment: Hi Jhon, i guess my above edit is what you are looking for. See if it is working for you